# Android: How to retrieve a single data from a web server and display it to a textview?

Tags: java, android, android-networking

i want to display an employee last clock-in from a web server. The problem is i'm not really sure how to retrieve a single last clock-in and display it to a textview. Here is my code, JSONParser.java:

```
package com.example.win7.simpleloginapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    int timeout=10000; //in milisecond = 10 detik

// constructor
public JSONParser() {
    //timeout = new Values().gettimeout();
}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketException ste)
    {
        Log.e("Timeout Exception: ", ste.toString());
    }
    catch (ConnectTimeoutException e)
    {
        Log.e("Timeout Exception: ", e.toString());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
    }
}
```

ServerRequest.java:

```
package com.example.win7.simpleloginapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.io.HttpRequestParser;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ServerRequest   {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
    public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS =  ".................net";

    final static String TAG_USER = "user";

    private Context mContext;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    public static final String NameStr = "Name";

    JSONArray user;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    public ServerRequest(Context context) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing..");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
        mContext = context;

    }

    public void storeUserDataInBackground(user user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
    progressDialog.show();
    new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();
}

public void fetchUserDataInBackground(user user, GetUserCallback callBack) {
    progressDialog.show();
    new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, callBack).execute();
}

public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    user user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();

        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://.........................../register.php");
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(null);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    }
}

public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask< Void, Void, user> {
    user user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected user doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("................................../fetchUserData.php");

        user returnedUser = null;
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if(jObject.length()==0)
            {
                returnedUser = null;

            }
            else
            {
                String Name1 = jObject.getString("Name");
                //String Name1 = "ekin";

                storeData(Name1);

                //Name1 = "hello";

                returnedUser = new user(user.username, user.password);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnedUser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(user returnedUser) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(returnedUser);
        super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);

    }

}

public SharedPreferences getSharedPref(){
    return mContext.getSharedPreferences(mContext.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void storeData(String Name1) {


    getSharedPref().edit().putString("data", Name1).apply();
}

public String getData(){


    return getSharedPref().getString("data", "");
    }

}
```

And here is the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.win7.simpleloginapp;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AnalogClock;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DigitalClock;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.location.LocationListener;

import com.example.win7.simpleloginapp.model.JSONParser2;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends  ActionBarActivity  {

    Button button_logout;
    TextView etUsername , etName, lastTimeDisp, lastDateDisp;       //baru
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    Button clockIN1, clockOUT1;
    Date date = new Date();
    String AndroidId;
    String username;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;
    private TextView locationText;
    private TextView addressText;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LocationManager locationMangaer = null;
    private LocationListener locationListener = null;
    private Button btnGetLocation = null;
    private EditText editLocation = null;
    private ProgressBar pb = null;
    private static final String TAG = "Debug";
    private Boolean flag = false;
    JSONArray user = null;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    public static final String TAG_USER = "user";
    public static final String TAG_STAFF_ID = "staffID";
    public static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
    public static final String TAG_TIME = "time";
    public static final String TAG_LONG = "longitude";
    public static final String TAG_LAT = "latitude";
    private Button scannerButton;
    private Button camButton;
    String staffIDStr, dateStr, timeStr, latitudeStr, longitudeStr;
    String user_name;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static final String mypreference = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String NameStr = "Name";
    ActionBar actionbar;
    TextView textview;
    LayoutParams layoutparams;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBarTitleGravity();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)         getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your device",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
           showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3B5999")));
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    lastTimeDisp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastTimeDisp);      //baru
    lastDateDisp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastDateDisp);      //baru
    button_logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);
    AnalogClock ac = (AnalogClock) findViewById(R.id.analogClock1);
    DigitalClock dc = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);
    clockIN1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clockIN);
    clockOUT1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clockOUT);
    etUsername.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
    etName.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("lastActivity", getClass().getName());
    editor.apply();     //baru - tukar commit() ke apply()
    ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(getApplicationContext());
    ServerRequest2 serverRequest2 = new ServerRequest2(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d("", "The value is : " + serverRequest.getData());

    String username1 = serverRequest.getData();
    String timeL = serverRequest2.getData();
    String dateL = serverRequest2.getData();

    etName.setText(username1);
    lastTimeDisp.setText(timeL);        //baru
    lastDateDisp.setText(dateL);     //baru

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    addressText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
    replaceMapFragment();

    clockIN1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); //set to current time

            clockIN1.setClickable(false);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            dateStr = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            timeStr = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            staffIDStr = etUsername.getText().toString();
            new createClockIn().execute();
            clockIN1.setEnabled(false);
            clockIN1.setClickable(false);
        }
    });
    userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
}

private void ActionBarTitleGravity() {
    actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    layoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    textview.setText("MysysESS");
    textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textview.setTextSize(25);
    textview.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionbar.setCustomView(textview);
}

class createClockIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("LOADING.");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_STAFF_ID, staffIDStr));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DATE, dateStr));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TIME, timeStr));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LONG, longitudeStr));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LAT, latitudeStr));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://.........................../createClockIN.php", "POST", params);

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                finish();
            } else {
                return "gagal_database";
            }
        } catch (JSONException e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "gagal_koneksi_or_exception";
        }
        return "sukses";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("gagal_database")) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is a problem , check your connection DB!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("gagal_koneksi_or_exception")) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is a problem , check your connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("sukses")) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Lets work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String staffID1 = etUsername.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", staffID1);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

//on start function login function
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (authenticate() == true)
        displayUserDetails();
    else
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class));
}

private boolean authenticate() {
    return userLocalStore.getUserLoggedIn();
}

private void displayUserDetails() {
    user user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();

    etUsername.setText(user.username);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    LinearLayout main_view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.logout:
            userLocalStore.clearUserData();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, login.class));
            finish();
            return true;

        case R.id.history:
            if (item.isChecked())
                item.setChecked(false);
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            String username1 = etUsername.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListHistory.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", username1);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        case R.id.location:
            if (item.isChecked())
                item.setChecked(false);
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            String username2 = etUsername.getText().toString();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationActivity.class);
            intent2.putExtra("username", username2);
            startActivity(intent2);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // super.onBackPressed(); // Comment this super call to avoid calling finish()
}

public void callBackDataFromAsyncTask(String address) {
    addressText.setText(address);
}

private void replaceMapFragment() {
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    View frag = findViewById(R.id.map);
    frag.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener());
}

private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener() {
    return new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

            LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();

            Marker marker;
            marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
            locationText.setText("You are at [" + longitude + " ; " + latitude + " ]");

            longitudeStr = Double.toString(longitude);
            latitudeStr = Double.toString(latitude);

            if ((longitude > 101.650000 && longitude < 101.670000 && latitude > 2.925000 && latitude < 2.927000) ||
                (longitude > 101.640000 && longitude < 101.660000 && latitude > 2.900000 && latitude < 2.920000) ||
                (longitude > 101.680000 && longitude < 101.700000 && latitude > 3.140000 && latitude < 3.170000) ||
                (longitude > 103.620000 && longitude < 103.640000 && latitude > 1.640000 && latitude < 1.660000))

            {
                clockIN1.setEnabled(true);
                scannerButton.setEnabled(true);
                camButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU ARE NOT IN THE OFFICE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                clockIN1.setEnabled(false);
                scannerButton.setEnabled(false);
                camButton.setEnabled(false);
            }

            new GetAddressTask(MainActivity.this).execute(String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude));
        }
    };
}

private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Settings your GPS",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {
                            Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                        }
                    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
    }

}
```

For your information, I have to retrieve the data from another web server url(http://........................./lastClock.php) and the name of the entity from the table is dclkrec(represent date) and cclktime(represent time).

Any help from you guys would be very appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a lot of wheel reinvention here. There are tools for networking and serialising/deserialising data.

For networking I can recommend [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Working with JSON objects [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Try these and your life will be much easier. Trust me. It is worth investing a little time.